# Making the textarea to take up full width in css table layout

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble making a form using tables. I'm trying to make the `<textarea>` comment box row take up the full width. The problem is unknown to me, as I don't know why it won't work.

```css
.full_width {
  width: 100%
}
.table {
  display: table; width: 100%;
}
.table_row {
  display: table-row; width: 100%;
}
.table_cell {
  display: table-cell
}
.label {
  display: block
}
.two_cell
{
    width: 48%;
}
#company_cell
{
    padding-left: 4%;
}
.table_cell {
  padding-bottom: 18px
}
```

```html
<form class="table" method="post">
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_row full_width">
            <div class="table_cell">
                <span>Name</span>
                <input name="name" class="full_width" type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="table_cell">
                <span>Company</span>
                <input name="company" class="full_width" type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_row full_width">
            <div class="table_row">
                <span>Comment</span>
            </div>
            <div class="table_row full_width">
                <textarea name="comment" class="full_width" value="SEND"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the fiddle I'm playing around with https://jsfiddle.net/bpo7tujp/

Comment: Just a question, is there a reason why you'd want to use tables?

Comment: It would be easier for me to make it responsive later. Isn't it good practice to use tables to grid a form?

Comment: Not at all! Divs are much better when used responsively than tables. You could look into Bootstrap?

Comment: Wait so it's bad practice?

Comment: Take a look at this, this would be much better for responsiveness - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: You definitely do not, and should not be using tables for this. And even more confusing is why you are using divs instead of an actual table?? This is some wonky stuff.

Comment: nb. css tables != html tables. HTML tables are semantically purposed for tabulated content (data), CSS tables are for tabulated layouting which though associated with tabulated content, is not inherently the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of your nested markup isn't wholly valid- in addition the logic conflicts somewhat.

### Solution 1: `table-caption`

What you are effectively after is a CSS version of `colspan`, you can achieve this by changing your HTML to that below, and implementing `table-caption`

```css
.full_width {
  width: 100%
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table_row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.table_cell {
  display: table-cell
}
.label {
  display: block
}
.two_cell {
  width: 48%;
}
#company_cell {
  padding-left: 4%;
}
.table_cell {
  padding-bottom: 18px
}
.table_caption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<form class="table" method="post">
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_cell">
      <span>Name</span>
      <input name="name" class="full_width" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="table_cell">
      <span>Company</span>
      <input name="company" class="full_width" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_caption">
    <span>Comment</span>
    <br />
    <textarea name="comment" class="full_width" value="SEND"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Solution 2 (advised): No tables

With that said, you would be far better not using tables for layouting, as evidenced by how simple it is to create the same:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <span>Name</span>
    <input name="name" class="full_width" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span>Company</span>
    <input name="company" class="full_width" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<span>Comment</span>
<textarea name="comment" class="full_width" value="SEND"></textarea>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered somewhat of a hack? It works but say I wanted more comment rows. It wouldn't look very nice in code.

Comment: Indeed, with that in mind I would err on the side of keeping tables reserved for tabulated data, and not layouting (although it is not expressly prohibited). Using tables for layouts introduces a fair amount of constraints

Comment: So what do you suggest I do instead to grid the form? Can you show me a fiddle of what you would do?

Comment: I've added an example without using tables

Comment: Alright so I have to admit I've been layout sites using tables for a while now. I'll leave the current site the way it is and just layout the form without using tables.

Comment: I don't understand what you consider tabulated content and what you consider tabulated layouting. Say I have a website that has a top header, a middle section with a blog and side bar. . Q1: In that case using css tables is good? Q2: Say if I had to layout a form like this one in the blog section, you say I should not use tables and instead do stuff like you did in solution 2. Is that correct?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Only use tables to display data / matrix information :)